# Use a reference list instead of adding to powershell script

Tags: excel, powershell

I have a txt file clients.txt that contains

c:\report1.xlm

c:\report2.xml

I want this to run against each xml

```
$ws = $wb.Sheets.Item('Report')
$ws.UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates($Columns)
$page = "Report"
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to substitute 'Report' with the xml reference from  clients.txt?

If so:

```
$reports = get-content c:\clients.txt
$reports | ForEach-Object {
    $ws = $wb.Sheets.Item($_)
    $ws.UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates($Columns)
    $page = "Report"
}
```

I'm not 100% sure what you are attempting to do.